# Determining gender of words

Tags: nlp

I'm looking to anonymise text, and one of the tasks is to remove references to the gender of a person being referenced. It is OK, but not preferable, if a little bit of meaning is lost (a pragmatic consequence of the fact this would be automated).

Words like he/she/him/her imply the gender of the person being referred to. These are the words I'm looking for.

Given one of these words, I can normalise (likely by just picking one of the words), but I need to be able to identify them first.

My naive thought was to search through the dictionary for any word with a definition that specifies a gender. That works, but is quite noisy.

Is there a better method for determining gender-specific words (in English), or a (preferably automated) method for determining them?

Comment: Try [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/). This site is just for programming problems.

Comment: I'll try there too, but this is a question about *automating* this. I'll rephrase the question.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html#gender-identification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any idea of the platform/language/software that you will use to automate that task?

For instance, you could probably try this [Gate](https://gate.ac.uk/) plugin: [Pronoun Annotator](https://github.com/philgooch/Pronoun_Annotator).

It is able to annotate pronouns with their gender. That could help you in your task.

Comment: Thanks, that looks quite good. I'll be using Python, but to generate the list, it doesn't really matter.